# PowerShell Invoke-Command connection error

Tags: powershell, remoting, winrm

I'm trying to enable PSRemoting from my local machine which is not connected to the domain, but is in the same subnet, to a VM that's part of our domain.

I have gone through all the set up that I can think of.

- WinRM is running on both machines (and have had quickconfig run)
- firewall is configured on both machines
- both machines have each other added to their trusted hosts
- `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on both machines

Pinging and remote desktop sessions and all that stuff works fine.

And yet `Test-WSMan` still gets me:

> Connecting to remote server DC01 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Any ideas of where to go next? I did look in the `about_Remote_Troubleshooting` file but didn't see anything that helped me.

**Edit:** After some messing around with other commands and trying to start a `New-PSSession` on a number of machines I get the above error on just DC01, which is an RDP host. With another machine, DC02, it works just fine. And with a 3rd machine, DC03, I get the following error

> The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting.

Which in the about_Remote_Troubleshooting points me to the

HOW TO CONNECT REMOTELY FROM A WORKGROUP-BASED COMPUTER

section. Under that it says configure for https, OR add the name of the remote computer to trusted hosts. Along with that, always use -credential and make sure that there is a password for the user account on the local machine.

All of which I meet (going by the non https route), but I think I will try the https setup.

Comment: Your error is listed in the section "HOW TO RESOLVE TIMEOUT ERRORS" of the remote troubleshooting help topic. That section also lists a couple things you could do to resolve the issue. Which of them did you try, and what were the results?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, the timeout error is "The WS-Management service cannot complete the operation within the time specified in OperationTimeout.", which is not my error. The suggestions listed under there are about extending the time before timeout. And they did not help.